# What are the benefits of having database in separate instance to main application?

Tags: design, database, database-design

Positive:

- Allow for horizontal scaling of app by replication of instances - without replicating the DB

Drawback:

- latency introduced between 2 machines

Is this something necessary for small systems?

Comment: Well, that's basically it. Sticking SQLite into your app is a [perfectly reasonable thing to do](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html). But note that replication also enables zero-downtime updates, which is desirable in many scenarios.

Comment: the latency is, in most cases, irrelevant. Even DBaaS connections through the WWW are fast enough. Security, resources and ALM are the main reasons to go one strategy or another.

Answer (score 2):

Database systems generally don't have fixed overheads - for instance, a table or index can be loaded from disk on demand or stored in RAM, with the same result but different performance. As such, many database systems are designed to make maximum use of available resources - they will claim as much RAM as allowed from the OS in advance and manage it internally, and assume they can use whatever CPU cores exist.

That strategy means they don't "play nicely" with other applications on the same instance, particularly those with unpredictable resource needs. You can set a limit for what the database preallocates, but set it too low and you waste resources, set it too high and your other applications can't deal with short bursts in demand.

Running two instances frees you from worrying about that conflict, and lets you pick appropriate resources for each part.